# How to solve sum always being 0?

Tags: java, object, methods, sum

I'm trying to write a method to sum two integers. There is no error in my code but when I try to use it, it always returns zero.

I wanted to have two methods: one to roll two random numbers and the other method was supposed to sum those numbers. There is nothing wrong with the roll part.

```java
public class GetSum {
    
    private Num num1;
    private Num num2;
    
    public GetSum(){
        num1 = new Number();
        num2 = new Number();
    }
    
        
    public void setNum1(Num num1){
        this.num1 = new Num(num1);
    }
    
    public Num getNum1(){
        return new Num(num1);
    }
    
    public void setNum2(Num num2){
        this.num2 = new Num(num2);
    }
    
    public Num getNum2(){
        return new Num(num2);
    }
    
    public void roll(){
        num1.roll();
        num2.roll();
    }
    
    public int getNumSum (){
        GetSum dice1 = new GetSum();
        GetSum dice2 = new GetSum();
        int x = dice1.getNum2().getFaceValue();
        int y = dice1.getNum1().getFaceValue();
        return x + y;
    } 
}
```

What I tried

```java
GetSum x = new GetSum();
x.roll();
System.out.println(x.getNum1().getFaceValue());
System.out.println(x.getNum2().getFaceValue());
System.out.println(x.getNumSum());
```

I get two random numbers but the sum is always zero.

Comment: please include a [mre] - we cannot see how `Number` is implemented (sure not the standard class with that name)

Answer (score 1):

Your `getNumSum` method creates two new `GetSum` instances and sums the values from one of them instead of summing the values from the data members you already have:

```
public int getNumSum (){
    int x = getNum2().getFaceValue();
    int y = getNum1().getFaceValue();
    return x + y;
}
```